# how to set label text using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code and I am not sure why I cant store the value into the data base

The error should be at this line :

```
document.getElementById('divPrize').innerHTML = prizes[x]['name'];
```

*Code:*

```
// Now we can work out the prize won by seeing what prize segment startAngle and endAngle the relativeAngle is between.
for (x = 0; x < (prizes.length); x ++)
{
    if ((relativeAngle >= prizes[x]['startAngle']) && (relativeAngle <= prizes[x]['endAngle']))
    {
        // Do something with the knowlege. For this example the user is just alerted, but you could play a sound,
        // change the innerHTML of a div to indicate the prize etc - up to you.
        // store db 

        document.getElementById('divPrize').innerHTML = prizes[x]['name'];
        document.getElementById('<%=lblPrize.ClientID %>').attributes['Text'] = prize[x]['name'];

        alert("You won " + prizes[x]['name'] + "!\nClick 'Play Again' to have another go.");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide code on jsfiddle

Comment: Hey, This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GPD24/

Answer (score 1):

Use `innerHTML` property

```
 document.getElementById('<%=lblPrize.ClientID %>').innerHTML = prize[x]['name'];
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('<%=lblPrize.ClientID %>').attributes['Text'] = prize[x]['name'];
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/J3wRD/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ...

```
document.getElementById('<%=lblPrize.ClientID %>').innerHTML = prize[x]['name'];
```